# User: is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to deploy my Node.js serverless application to AWS using this command `serverless deploy` but I keep getting this error

```
User: arn:aws:iam::900989174731:user/obafemitayor2 is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:900989174731:stack/app/* because no permissions boundary allows the cloudformation:DescribeStacks action
```

I have created a user and granted the following permissions to the user.

1. AWSLambdaFullAccess
2. AmazonS3FullAccess
3. CloudFrontFullAccess
4. AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess

and I also added this policy to my group

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449904348000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ListStacks",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but I still get that error. Any Ideas?

Comment: You must have other policies denying the access, or you are using wrong user/account.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, you are missing the `cloudformation:DescribeStacks` in your policy.

Comment: How do I add that in my policy?

Comment: The permission is part of `AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess` which OP claims he/she has.

Comment: My bad, must have overlooked that. Thank you for making me aware! :)